# Bundle install, how to avoid using the library from source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, bundle, gemset

I want to install a library to my `rvm gemsets`, but this library is not available using in the `gem install`. I have to install it from source

I do `bundle install` and it went well, except that It does not install the lib to the gemset but only the dependencies.

And I notice in the log this line
`Using xxx (a.b.c) from source at .`

xxx is the library itself with version a.b.c and I can only use the library when I am in the source folder.

How to force to copy the library to the gemsets folder ?

Comment: What do you mean "install it from source"? Do you have a local gem file you want to install? So a gem file that isn't on a remote server, but only on your computer?

Comment: It's a github repo and I clone it to my computer, cd to it and do a `bundle install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do one of the following:

1.: Use the :git option in your Gemfile for direct git(hub) access

`gem 'gemname', :git => 'git://github.com/foo'`

2.: Use the :path option in your Gemfile for local access

`gem 'gemname', :path => '/path/to/foo'`

3.: Install the local gem and use it in your Gemfile

```
# command line
gem install '/path/to/foo'

# Gemfile
gem 'foo'
```

Comment: The (3) step is to run `gem install` and `gem 'foo'` or should I put it in the Gemfile ?

Comment: No, you have to run `gem install` first, but instead of specifying only the name, you specify the local path to your gem folder. Then you can simply put `gem 'foo'` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`